# Named slot has property not referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, devexpress, devextreme

My parent component's template :

```
<div class="no-filter-container">
        <span v-if="errorMessage" style="color: red; text-align: center;">Ajoutez au moins une opération !</span>
        <DxFilterBuilder
        ref="filterBuilderRefName"
        :fields="fields"
        @value-changed="updateTexts"
        >
            <DxCustomOperation
            :calculate-filter-expression="calculateFilterExpression"
            name="anyof"
            caption="Parmi"
            icon="check"
            editor-template="editorComponentTemplate"
            />
            <template #editorComponentTemplate="{ data: conditionInfo }">
                <EditorComponent
                :condition-info="conditionInfo"/>
            </template>
        </DxFilterBuilder>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addFilter">Sauvegarder</button>
    </div>
```

My child component:

```
<template>
<DxTagBox
  :value="conditionInfo.value"
  :items="conditionInfo.field.lookup.dataSource"
  :input-attr="{ 'aria-label': 'Categorie' }"
  @value-changed="onValueChanged"
  :hideSelectedItems="true"
  style="width: 200px"
/>
</template>



<script>
import DxTagBox from 'devextreme-vue/tag-box';
    export default {
        components: {
            DxTagBox,
        },
        props: {
            conditionInfo: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => {},
            },
        },
        methods: {
            onValueChanged(e) {
                this.conditionInfo.setValue(e.value && e.value.length ? e.value : null);
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.conditionInfo)
        }
    };
</script>
```

I plan on extracting data from conditionInfo. It is not referenced in my parent's template. I get the

> Property or method "conditionInfo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Error from Vue. Unsure why.

Package used and working code :
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FilterBuilder/Customization/Vue/Dark/